# Unable to pass C struct into function

Tags: c, struct

I'm having trouble passing a struct into a function and I am running into an error:

> 'PWM_PINS' undeclared (first use in this function)

I am typically able to do this in a C++ compiler without any trouble. I would appreciate some advice as to what I might be doing wrong here.

I have included the relevant parts from the header and c file below.

**pwm.h file:**

```
typedef struct PWM_tag{
    int PWM_1;
    int PWM_2;
    int PWM_3;
    int PWM_4;
    int PWM_5;
    int PWM_6;
} PWM;

void PWM_Set( uint32_t channelNum, uint32_t cycle, PWM PWN_PINS );
```

**pwm.c file:**

```
#include "pwm.h"
 void PWM_Set( uint32_t ChannelNum, uint32_t cycle, PWM PWN_PINS)
    {
        if ( ChannelNum == 1 )
        {
            LPC_PWM1->MR0 = cycle;
            LPC_PWM1->MR1 = PWM_PINS.PWM_1;
            LPC_PWM1->MR2 = PWM_PINS.PWM_2;
            LPC_PWM1->MR3 = PWN_PINS.PWM_3;
            LPC_PWM1->MR4 = PWM_PINS.PWM_4;
            LPC_PWM1->MR5 = PWM_PINS.PWM_5;
            LPC_PWM1->MR6 = PWM_PINS.PWM_6;

        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a parameter called `PWN_PINS` (with an `N`), but you are referring to `PWM_PINS` (with an `M`).

Fixing this typo will address this particular error. There may be more errors, though - it's hard to tell, because the snippet does not show essential parts, such as the declaration of `LPC_PWM1` variable.

Comment: Thank you! Wow... very embarrassing, but you probably saved me an hour more of banging my head against the table :)

Comment: @stephf0716 That's OK, something like this has happened to me more times than I'm willing to admit :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there misspelling in the code?

The function parameter is **PWN_PINS**.But the code have 5 **PWM_PINS**, and one **PWN_PINS**.

I think what you should do is to change all **PWN_PINS** to **PWM_PINS**.